# How to keep a count through a recursive method when trying to fill an array in a BST

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to fill an array in through a preorder tree traversal, but I think I've made a mistake with how to keep the counter correct. My toString() method calls on the preorder method, but it just outputs null. How can I fix this?

```
public AVLTreeNode[] preorder()
{
    /*
     * return an array of AVLTreeNodes in preorder
     */
    AVLTreeNode[] preorder = new AVLTreeNode[size];
    int count = 0;
    return preorder(root, count, preorder);
}

private AVLTreeNode[] preorder(AVLTreeNode data, int count, AVLTreeNode preorder[])
{
    if (data == null)
    {
        return preorder;
    }
    preorder[count] = data;
    if (data.getLeft() != null)
    {
        preorder(data.getLeft(), count++, preorder);
    }
    if (data.getRight() != null)
    {
        preorder(data.getRight(), count++, preorder);
    }
    return preorder;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` has the wrong value because on subsequent calls of `preorder` with `count++` the actual value of `count` is passed to the method and *afterwards* `count` is increased. Also after returning from the left node `count` has probably a higher value than what you pass to the call for the right node. There are two solutions:

1. Use a global `private int count;` and set it to `0` before calling `preorder`.
2. Return the new `count` instead of the `AVLTreeNode[]` and assign it to the local `count` of the method to get the correct value. `AVLTreeNode[] preorder` could also be a private variable.

Comment: now I am getting an output, but its not the correct one. With input {3,1,5,2} its giving me the output {3,1,5,null}. I checked that the tree contained the value 2 and it came back true. Any idea why it would miss the right child of 1?